# Twilio node - Browser to phone StatusCallback events

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to get back StatusCallback events when I dial from my browser to phone call.

When user clicks on dial in browser I am sending the following response to twilio:

```
  const dial = twiml.dial({
    callerId: Meteor.settings.private.twilio.TWILIO_CALLER_ID,
    answerOnBridge: true,
    record: "record-from-answer-dual",
    StatusCallbackEvent: ["initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"],
    StatusCallback,
    recordingStatusCallback: recordURLCallback,
  });
  dial.number(toNumber);
```

I have registered webhook both in twilio console and also sending via command but i'm not receiving 'ringing', 'answered' events from twilio

```
   WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/twilio-status-callback", function( req, res, next ) {
     console.log('***status url callback***');
     var body = "";
     req.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
       body += data;
     }));
     req.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
      body = qs.parse(body)
      console.log(body);

      res.end();
    }));
  });
```

I am only receiving `completed` event, how to get other statuses to so that I can show ringing UI when it is ringing and hangup button when answered?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your example code you don't include an option for `StatusCallback` so there is no webhook for Twilio to call, only a `recordingStatusCallback`. Also, the Node library actually translates the keys from lower-camel-case, so the keys should be `statusCallback`. Try updating the code to something like this and let me know how it goes:

```
const dial = twiml.dial({
  callerId: Meteor.settings.private.twilio.TWILIO_CALLER_ID,
  answerOnBridge: true,
  record: "record-from-answer-dual",
  statusCallbackEvent: ["initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"],
  statusCallback: statusURLCallback,
  recordingStatusCallback: recordURLCallback,
});
dial.number(toNumber);
```